# why I do not need to emit the event?

Tags: node.js

```
var fs=require('fs');

var myReadStream = fs.createReadStream('./readMe.txt','utf8');

myReadStream.on('data',function(chunck){
    console.log('new chunk received');
    console.log(chunck);
})
```

I'm following a tutorial on youtube, and I found something that makes me wonder, how can the event myReadStream.on be executed without emitting it like

```
myReadStream.emit('data', './readMe.txt');
```

Hope anyone can answer this thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to emit `data` if you create your own event emitter from scratch:

```
new EventEmitter()
.on('data', console.log)
.emit('data', 'some data');
```

`createReadStream` returns a readable stream. It's stream's duty to emit `data` events when there is data available.